# Can a PropertiesFactoryBean read a value from application.yml?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-java-config

My project has a dependency that requires a set a properties object that can be read by @Value annotations:

```
@Value("#{myProps['property.1']}")
```

To do this in JavaConfig, I'm using the following:

```
@Bean(name="myProps")
public static PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("myprops.properties"));
    return bean;
}
```

This works as expected. My properties look as follows:

```
property.1=http://localhost/foo/bar
property.2=http://localhost/bar/baz
property.3=http://localhost/foo/baz
```

I'm using Spring Boot for this project, so I'd love to be able to do something like the following:

```
myprops.properties:
    property.1=${base.url}/foo/bar
    property.2=${base.url}/bar/baz
    property.3=${base.url}/foo/baz
```

Then I could configure the base.url based on different profiles.

```
application.yml:

    base:
      url: http://localhost

    ---
    spring:
      profiles: staging
    base:
      url: http://staging

    ---
    spring:
      profiles: production
    base:
      url: http://production
```

I've tried to do this and it doesn't work. As a workaround, I've created three different .properties files (myprops.properties, myprops-staging.properties, etc.) and loaded them with three different @Configuration classes. This works, but seems cumbersome.

```
@Configuration
public class DefaultConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="myProps")
    public static PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("myprops.properties"));
        return bean;
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("staging")
public class StagingConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="myProps")
    public static PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("myprops-staging.properties"));
        return bean;
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("production")
public class ProductionConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="myProps")
    public static PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("myprops-production.properties"));
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to configure my PropertiesFactoryBean to read values from application.yml? If not, is there an easier way to configure properties with JavaConfig?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing this programmatically and it gives me the behavior I was looking for:

```
@Value("${base.url}")
private String baseUrl;

@Bean(name = "myProps")
public PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("myprops.properties"));
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();

    // replace ${base.url} in values
    Properties props = bean.getObject();
    Enumeration names = props.propertyNames();

    while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = names.nextElement().toString();
        String value = props.getProperty(name);
        if (value.contains("${base.url}")) {
            props.setProperty(name, value.replace("${base.url}", baseUrl));
        }
    }

    bean.setLocalOverride(true);
    bean.setProperties(props);
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();

    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Base URL: " + baseUrl);
    }

    return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are really looking do there, and you don't really say what doesn't work, but it looks like you want to mix YAML and properties formats for your external config? Why not just use "application.yml"? If I were doing something like that, and I *needed* to use a properties file for some reason as well, then I would use `@PropertySource` on one of my `SpringApplication` source files (that way the placeholders should be replaced when the values are resolved I think).